# Grunt: "spawn ENOENT" using svg2storeicons?

Tags: node.js, cordova, icons, gruntjs

I'm trying to use grunt to build my icons from a svg file using [this plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-svg2storeicons). I'm new to Grunt so it might be something obvious. Here's my `Gruntfile.js`...

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svg2storeicons');
    grunt.initConfig({
        svg2storeicons: {
            all_stores: {
                src: 'app/res/icon.svg',
                dest: 'www/'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['svg2storeicons']);
};
```

This it my stack trace...

```
C:\path\to\project\>grunt --stack
Running "svg2storeicons:all_stores" (svg2storeicons) task
>> spawn ENOENT
Warning: Task "svg2storeicons:all_stores" failed. Use --force to continue.
Error: Task "svg2storeicons:all_stores" failed.
    at Task.<anonymous> (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:197:15)
    at null._onTimeout (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:225:33)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

`spawn ENOENT` means node.js is trying to spawn a process but the process doesn't exist. My guess looking at that plugin, is graphicsmagick isn't installed or cannot be found where it is installed.

See: https://github.com/PEM--/grunt-svg2storeicons#graphicsmagick

Comment: I thought that was only required for Mac?

Comment: That grunt plugin uses https://github.com/aheckmann/gm which shells out for the commands, aka is typing the commands in your shell for you. So if those commands don't exist on your machine, it will fail. You can try installing graphicsmagick for windows: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-windows.html Their docs seem to only show support for Linux and OSX, if it works send them a PR and let them know it works for Windows as well. :)